# Not able to add extra content to an existing PDF using PDFBox

Tags: java, pdfbox

I am using PdfBox to generate pdf with an existing Pdf containing the template which has to be used for every Pdf that i want to generate.

But When i try to load the template pdf and wants to write something in it, all previous contains were removed.

So i want both the content should be shown.

Please suggest any solution for it.

Here is the code i am trying to do :

```
//Loading an existing document 
File file = new File("/home/spaneos/ScoringReports-TM-110617.pdf"); 
PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(file); 

//Retrieving the pages of the document 
PDPage page = document.getPage(0);
PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(document, page);
//Begin the Content stream 
contentStream.beginText(); 

//Setting the font to the Content stream
contentStream.setFont( PDType1Font.TIMES_ROMAN, 16 );

//Setting the leading
contentStream.setLeading(14.5f);

//Setting the position for the line
contentStream.newLineAtOffset(25, 725);

String text1 = "This is an example of adding text to a page in the pdf document.we can add as many lines";
String text2 = "as we want like this using the ShowText()  method of the ContentStream class";

//Adding text in the form of string
contentStream.showText(text1);
contentStream.newLine();
contentStream.showText(text2);

//Creating PDImageXObject object
PDImageXObject pdImage = PDImageXObject.createFromFile("/home/spaneos/Downloads/man-161282_960_720.png",document);

//creating the PDPageContentStream object
PDPageContentStream contents = new PDPageContentStream(document, page);

contentStream.endText();

System.out.println("Content added");

//Closing the PDPageContentStream object
contents.close();   

//Closing the content stream
contentStream.close();

//Saving the document 
document.save(System.getProperty("user.dir").concat("/PdfBox_Examples/sample.pdf"));

//Closing the document  
document.close();
```

Comment: Please include your code.

Comment: As your question does not illustrate what exactly you do, we can only say that you do something wrong...

Comment: yes i have added my code now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You create the `PDPageContentStream` instances like this

```
PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(document, page);
[...]
PDPageContentStream contents = new PDPageContentStream(document, page);
```

Creating it using this constructor *replaces* any existing content streams with the new one. Instead use this one:

```
PDPageContentStream contents = new PDPageContentStream(document, page, AppendMode.APPEND, true, true);
```

`AppendMode.APPEND` here tells PDFBox to append the new stream, the first `true` tells it to compress the stream, and the second `true` tells it to reset the graphics state at the start of your added stream.

Furthermore, you don't really use the second content stream...